# Postgres reference subquery in case statement

Tags: postgresql, subquery, cross-join

I'm trying to reference a subquery to use the value in a case statement. But, inside the SELECT statement I cannot reference the `next_creation` as it simply complains that the column does not exist. I thought about wrapping the entire query in a CASE statement but the CASE statement would require me to run the query multiple times and that seems silly.

I also tried to do a `CROSS JOIN` with the subquery, but it complains about not being able to reference tg inside the subquery.    Kernel error: ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "tg" HINT:  There is an entry for table "tg", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

I also tried using a `WITH` but it basically has the same result as CROSS JOIN. So I even tried appending two `WITH` clauses with the first query being the same at the main `OUTER` query so the second with could use the values....I got some error.

Is there any way to reference the subquery like stick it in a variable to use while still allowing the subquery to utilize the `tg` from the outer query?

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT
        tg2.created
    FROM tocom t
    LEFT JOIN tocom_g_assoc ON tocom_g_assoc.table_id = t.id AND tocom_g_assoc.tocom_g_id != tg.id
    LEFT JOIN tocom_g tg2 ON tg2.id = tocom_g_assoc.tocom_g_id
    WHERE t.id IN ( SELECT t_id FROM tocom_g_assoc WHERE tocom_g_assoc.tocom_g_id = tg.id )
        AND tg2.createdt > tg.created
        AND tg2.created IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY tg2.created ASC
    LIMIT 1
) next_creation

/*
Here I want to do as CASE statement, but for argument sake,
a simple next_creation - tg.dissolved_at would do
*/

FROM wp p
LEFT JOIN tocom_g tg ON tg.id = p.tocom_g_id
WHERE tg.dissolved_at IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized the issue.

So I left it as a select, returning the subquery. Then I wrapper the whole thing in another select and made that query the from statement. I could then do whatever I wanted with the returned values.